# Change ISO value while recording - Android Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm trying to implement a video capture app following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) sample.

I'm able to change ISO value, update my preview and make a video using that value, but I'd also like to let my users change ISO values while recording without interrupting video, but I wasn't able to find out how.
This is the code I'm using to start recording:

```
private void startRecording() {
    final Camera2Controller me = this;
    try {
        this.mediaRecorder = this.prepareMediaRecorder(); // Nothing special about it
        final CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = this.getCameraDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        this.updateRequestForCapture(requestBuilder);
        ArrayList<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        surfaces.add(this.surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        surfaces.add(this.mediaRecorder.getSurface());
        for (Surface target : surfaces) {
            requestBuilder.addTarget(target);
        }
        this.captureRequest = requestBuilder.build();
        this.getCameraDevice().createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    me.setCaptureSession(session);
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(me.captureRequest, null, null);
                    me.mediaRecorder.start();
                    me._isRecording = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        me._isRecording = false;
                        me.getCaptureSession().stopRepeating();
                        me.getCaptureSession().abortCaptures();
                        me.getCaptureSession().close();
                    }
                    catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
                        cae.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        me.mediaRecorder.reset();
                        me.mediaRecorder.release();
                        me.mediaRecorder = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                me._isRecording = false;
            }
        }, this);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        me._isRecording = false;
    }
}

public void updateRequestForCapture(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, this.ControlMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, this.AEMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, this.WhiteBalanceLock);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, this.ISO);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, this.ExposureTime);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, this.WhiteBalanceMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE, this.SceneMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, this.AFMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, this.AFTrigger);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, this.ColorCorrectionMode);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM, this.ColorSpaceTransform);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, this.ColorCorrectionGain);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?